# Finding the Sum based on Group using Flux Query - InfluxDB

Tags: mysql, grafana, influxdb, influxql, flux-influxdb

I am trying to use flux query language to find the sum of a column based on a person.
If I have the following input table:

[image]

How can I use a Flux Query to obtain the following output table:

[image]

I have tried something like this so far but I get errors:

```
from: (bucket: "example")
  |> range(start:v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r)=> r["_measurement"] == "test")
  |> group(columns: r["person"])
  |> reduce( fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: r._value + accumulator.sum}), identity: {sum: 0})
```

Comment: do u need flux query or mysql query. If I provide mysql query will you convert to flux query?

Comment: I need flux query. Is there an easy way to convert mysql query to flux query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost on the right way. You have already grouped by name and now you need to use function `sum`. Pay attention on last function - `|> group()` it's just for union table to one view.

```
|> group(columns: ["person"])
|> sum(column: "hoursSpent")
|> group()
```

---

I provide full of my query for debug:

```
import "array"

data = array.from(rows: [
  {person: "John Smith", sport: "Cycling", hoursSpent: 5},
  {person: "John Smith", sport: "Hiking", hoursSpent: 6},
  {person: "John Smith", sport: "Swimming", hoursSpent: 1},
  {person: "John Smith", sport: "Dancing", hoursSpent: 2},
  {person: "Nancy Jones", sport: "Badminton", hoursSpent: 10},
  {person: "Nancy Jones", sport: "Soccer", hoursSpent: 31},
  {person: "Nancy Jones", sport: "Basketball", hoursSpent: 8},
  {person: "Trevor John", sport: "Baseball", hoursSpent: 24},
  {person: "Trevor John", sport: "Water Polo", hoursSpent: 2},
])

data
 |> group(columns: ["person"])
 |> sum(column: "hoursSpent")
 |> group()
```

[image]

Comment: What should I do if I want |> sum(column: "a"), sum(column: "b"). call sum twice one time

Comment: @DinoStray can you provide a little example of data and what you expected?